# Text summarization

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I built a model for text summarization, I created a small document (text file) with its summary, then I trained the model on that, I created again the same type of document for test, the training and test documents are pretty similar but with different data.

For example, the training document contains:

```
name : train

family name : train
```

The test document:

```
name : test

family name : test
```

I was hoping that after training the model, it will remember the structure of the important sentences, after testing I've got an accuracy of 100%.

The problem is when I train the model on another document, the previous test gives lower accuracy, it's like it forgets the previous training.
here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(200,64, input_length=max_sent_length))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 
for i in range(0,len(xtrains)):
    model.fit(xtrains[i],ytrains[i], epochs=200, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)
```

I've searched about that and the answers I got is that refitting the model doesn't reset weights, so I was wondering why whenever I train the model on new documents I get lower accuracy for the previous tests, whereas at the beginning I received an accuracy of 100%.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How much is your training set?

Comment: I only trained it for 4 type of documents where each document contain between 7 and 15 sentences (no not that much), the same thing for the tests, i tested it for the same type of ducuments

Comment: There isn't simply enough data for it give you the accuracy you want.

Comment: But when i trained it on only one document it gave a better accuracy, the question is why when i train it on more, it gives lower accuracy.